# knockout nested bindings interfere with jquery click in IE7/IE8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, dom, knockout.js

It looks to me as if there is a bug in Knockout when used in IE7/IE8, but it may be a known issue or (even more likely) I am approaching things incorrectly and need to be corrected. I would appreciate any assistance you wonderful folks can provide.

When I bind a click handler to an element using jQuery's $.click() as shown below, it generally works fine in IE7/IE8/IE9. Where I run into problems is if the element (in this case a button, but it also applies to other element types from my testing) is inside of a the DOM structure being bound by Knockout. This only occurs in IE7/IE8, sadly, so the jsFiddle link I share at the bottom may be of limited value. In IE9 (unsurprisingly) the behavior works as expected.

This also does not seem to affect events bound without jQuery (using element.attachEvent in pure javascript).

```
<div data-bind="with:ContainerObject">
    <div data-bind="text:ContainedProperty"></div>
    <input id="alertButtonJQBad" type="button" value="jq/ko=broken" />
</div>

function jqClickBad() { alert("nested click() handler bound by jquery"); }
// this fires fine in IE9, but not in IE7/IE8:
$("#alertButtonJQBad").click(jqClickBad);
var viewModel = {
    ContainerObject: {
        ContainedProperty: "test"
    }
};
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/csiefken/WckWb/3/

Comment: I ended up just registering the handler after `ko.applyBindings()` as (workaround suggested by @Brandon). I recognize that this goes counter to the ko design philosophy. I'll see about refactoring it into a better format after I get my demo completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot even run the JS fiddle in IE8.  jsFiddle doesn't seem to display properly for me.

Generally speaking, if you are using regular jQuery event bindings instead of KO event bindings then you are going against the grain.  If you really need to use jQuery to register your handlers instead of Knockout event bindings, then either do the registration *after* `ko.applyBindings` or use live event handlers (by supplying css selectors to `$.on()`) so that your bindings will survive any potential DOM rewrites performed by Knockout.

Comment: This is exactly the type of recommendations I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: FWIW - Most of my woes are with IE7/IE8 falling to pieces. It's pretty hard to demo those on jsFiddle. :\